# geom_density: plot individual densities and mean density

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability-density, kernel-density

I have the following data:

```
x = c(
rnorm(mean=0.0, 100),
rnorm(mean=1.0, 100),
rnorm(mean=2.0, 200)
)

g = c(
rep('a', 100),
rep('b', 100),
rep('c', 200)
)

d = data.frame(x=x, g=as.factor(g))
```

I would like to plot the densities within each group *g*, along with the "mean density." However, instead of calculating the mean over all data points, I want to calculate a weighted mean over all groups (i.e. the mean of the individual density estimates).

Here is a very similar plot to the one I would like to produce:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d) + 
geom_density(aes(x=x, color=g)) + 
geom_density(aes(x=x), fill='#cccccc', alpha=.5)
```

However, in the above example, the mean density is estimated over all of the *data points* (i.e. the mean is roughly ~1.25). Instead, I want to plot the mean of the *density estimates*, which should have a mean of ~1.0.

[image]

Comment: I think you can accomplish this by using weights in the density estimation step. One way might be: `library(data.table); dtab=data.table(d); dtab[, weights:=(1/.N) / length(unique(tab$g)), by="g"]; ggplot() + geom_density(data=dtab, aes(x=x, weight=weights))`.

Comment: Good idea. I didn't think about that. Thanks!